# PortalID returns null reference error

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm using this function to allow users to login however portalid returns a null reference. I'm using an existing dnn to check if the user exists. But how I get the portalid to be used in a different program. This what I have so far

```
 int PID = DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings().PortalId;
    try
    {
        //validate username/password combination
        DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo myUser = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo();
        DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus userLoginStatus = new DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus();
        myUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.ValidateUser(PID, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, "", "", "", ref userLoginStatus);



        if (userLoginStatus == DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS ||
        userLoginStatus == DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUPERUSER)
        {
            //login the user ...
            DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.UserLogin(PID, myUser, "", "", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Home/Welcome.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error!! " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You're not going to want to use GetCurrentPortalSettings() because you're not using a portal, you're outside the portal. Check the other methods on PortalController to find one that'll accept a PortalID coming in that you can use.

Comment: when I use a PortalID it is saying cannot convert from 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalInfo' to 'int'

Comment: Yes you will need to determine some other way to figure out what PortalID someone is trying to use.

Comment: @ChrisHammond; so there is no other way to deal with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PortalController for that.

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;

//get a portal by ID
var portal = PortalController.Instance.GetPortal(PortalId);

//get the current portal
var portal = PortalController.Instance.GetCurrentPortalSettings();
```

Comment: where do I store portalID

Comment: Wherever you want. It's just an int variable.

Comment: I'm getting an error about unassigned local variable. What should I assign to that variable

Comment: And when I use var portal; this line   myUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.ValidateUser(portal, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, "", "", "", ref userLoginStatus); gives error about Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalInfo' to 'int'

Comment: A lot apparently. Create something like `int PortalId = 1`. And `portal` is a class, so access it's properties.

Comment: what are the properties

Comment: Okay. Stop there and do some C# tutorials first if you do not know what properties and unassigned variables are. Once you have basic knowledge go back to DNN programming.

Comment: i do know what those are. Just have never worked with DNN. Just thought there was a specific way to handle such

Comment: I'm getting this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Not really, all you need is contained in the `portal` object.

Comment: myUser = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.ValidateUser(portal, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, "", "", "", ref userLoginStatus); so this what I have what should I change

Comment: why does it still stay that the object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you assist me please

Comment: There is not much I can do. I've shown you 2 ways of getting the Portal Object. If it is null with the first that means that the PortalID is incorrect and that the Portal does not exist. The second means you are completely outside of the DNN context somehow. It's up to you to figure it out.

Comment: Let me ask this question, is it possible to use a dnn database in another program, Without referring to what I know have; is it possible to login from a different system using a dnn database because that's all I want from the dnn. to match the username and password. Additionally it would be null because how does it know which portal. Is there something to be added to the web config

Comment: Next question is there a way to find the portalID of the dnn.